# When the determinant of a matrix over the complex numbers is real, does it measure the area of some object?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say a matrix over the complex numbers has a real determinant. Can the determinant be associated with the area of some object?

For example, this matrix (which is the norm equation for quaternions:)

$$det\left\{\begin{matrix} x+yi & n+im \\ im-n & x-iy \end{matrix}\right\} = x^2 + y^2 + n^2+m^2$$

If not, is there any other geometric interpretation of the determinant of a matrix over the complex numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $M$ with complex entries, let $T$ be the corresponding linear mapping from $C^n$ to $C^n$. The same mapping can be considered as a linear mapping $T'$ from $R^{2n}$ to $R^{2n}$.

It is a fact that $\det T' = |\det T|^2$. Hence for any measurable subset $A$ of $C^n$, the $2n$-dimensional volume of $T(A)$ is $|\det T|^2$ times that of $A$.